# Transparency feature on my QGIS 3.10 is Opacity

Tags: transparency-opacity

When adding a raster layer to a vector layer, I am unable to make the top layer transparent. On getting into Layer Panel properties and checking it shows Opacity slider. Adjusting opacity at anything between 0 - 30% does not help. How do I manage this?

Comment: What do you mean by "adding a raster layer to a vector layer"?

Comment: Might be trivial, but did you check that the layer you want to be transparent is also above the other layer in the layer tree?